# Azure Bot missing info members added

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a little problem with Microsoft Azure Bot Framework, i created sample bot from microsoft guide but when i test it bot don't receive members info (name, role ed ecc) but receive only ID.

I use the webchat (javascript) taken from the microsoft guide to query the bot.

Bot function where i want get members info:

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){

            var member1 = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);

            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {

                    var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                    var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(welcomeCard, ssml: "Welcome to Bot Framework!");
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
                    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
```

Webchat code to query bot:

```
(async function() {
        const secret = 'XXX';
        const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
            headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${secret}`
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
        const {token} = await res.json();

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
          userID: 'WebChat_UserId',
          locale: 'en-US',
          username: 'Web Chat User',
          role: 'user
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
      );

      document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();

    })().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpB9B.png) user info from debug

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/team-chat-member-api-changes.

Comment: @ranusharao i tried but not working

Comment: So TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync works in one-on-one, group, and teams scoped conversations.
Have you looked at your manifest files to be sure that you have given the right scopes.
Also you could try
 await TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id, cancellationToken)